# Selenium Test not running using test container

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, testcontainers

My Selenium test is not running with my test container(docker).

Sample Config code

```
public class ChromeExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {

private BrowserWebDriverContainer browser;

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox","--headless","--disable-dev-shm-usage",
                "--disable-extensions","--verbose","--remote-debugging-port=9222","--disable-gpu");
        browser = new BrowserWebDriverContainer()
                .withCapabilities(chromeOptions);
        browser.start();

     
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(browser.getWebDriver());


       
    }
```

Dependencies in Build.gradle

```
    testImplementation ('com.codeborne:selenide:5.20.1')
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:selenium:1.16.3'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.16.3'
```

Getting Exception Like

```
Timeout waiting for result with exception
org.rnorth.ducttape.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for result with exception
    at app//org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:54)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.getWebDriver(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:292)
    at app//at.magenta.tau.taup.ui.setup.ChromeExtensionTau.beforeEach(ChromeExtensionTau.java:39)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachCallbacks$2(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:163)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:199)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachCallbacks(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:162)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:129)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.16.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.2.1', revision: 'ac4d0fdd4a'
System info: host: '2e6941fb4d93', ip: '172.22.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.2.1', revision: 'ac4d0fdd4a'
System info: host: '2e6941fb4d93', ip: '172.22.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.2.1', revision: 'ac4d0fdd4a'
System info: host: 'gajendra.khandelwal', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4d9:683e:9b45:74a4%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.3', java.version: '11.0.16.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-extensions, --verbose, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-extensions, --verbose, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.timeouts.Timeouts.callFuture(Timeouts.java:68)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.timeouts.Timeouts.getWithTimeout(Timeouts.java:43)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.lambda$getWebDriver$1(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:293)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.lambda$retryUntilSuccess$0(Unreliables.java:43)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '4.2.1', revision: 'ac4d0fdd4a'
System info: host: '2e6941fb4d93', ip: '172.22.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.2.1', revision: 'ac4d0fdd4a'
System info: host: '2e6941fb4d93', ip: '172.22.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.124-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.2.1', revision: 'ac4d0fdd4a'
System info: host: 'gajendra.khandelwal', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4d9:683e:9b45:74a4%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '12.3', java.version: '11.0.16.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-extensions, --verbose, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--no-sandbox, --headless, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --disable-extensions, --verbose, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}}}]
Capabilities {}
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:144)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:551)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:162)
    at app//org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer.lambda$null$0(BrowserWebDriverContainer.java:294)
    ... 4 more
```

If you see above My test is not working due to that but if i remove

```
 WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(browser.getWebDriver());
```

After removing this it will start working but it should work with this.

Apart from that i am able to see my test container got up when i run test it means my docker container is running properly.

Comment: What is `WebDriverRunner`?

Answer (score 1):

We recenty updated our [documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/webdriver_containers/) to reflect the correct way to instantiate the `WebDriver`:

```java
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(browser.getSeleniumAddress(), new ChromeOptions());
```

Please give it a try, and else, please share a [reproducer](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-repro). I also noticed that you are using the `junit-jupiter` module, but you don't use the actual extension in your example. Also, please make sure to use the latest version Testcontainers (`1.17.6`).